# html textarea using specific character set

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I would like to "force" a specific character set (ISO-8859-1) for a specific textarea html tag in a page.

I'm not sure if this is feasible either in HTML or using a JS technique, but to give an idea of what I would like to achieve:

```
<textarea character-set="ISO-8859-1"></textarea>
```

The above should allow the user to enter characters that are part only of the ISO-8859-1 character set, characters like € (EUR) should be blocked/displayed as dummy character.

I'm asking this since my website is integrated with a third-party service that only supports ISO-8859-1 characters and I want the user entering the message immediately see that some characters are not permitted.

Hope this make sense, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to only accept a given charset from within a form, this link to W3Schools forms with "accept-charset=yourTargetCharSet" shows how to force the form to only accept certain charsets.
(http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_accept_charset.asp)

Alternatively, you could capture and convert any inputted text as
required using the following ISO conversion references 
(http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_8859.asp)

```
//In this scenario you would want to ID your textarea and gather the
//inputted values something like the following

<textarea id="getMeName"></textarea>
<textarea id="getMeOther"></textarea>

<script>
var thisFormNameData = document.getElementById("getMyName") 
//or the other id, and then you could manipulate that variable as
//needed to better suit your ISO within a UTF-8 doc
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you, I've tried the first approach but this sort of validation happens after the submission of the form, instead I need to do this "translation"/"check" live while the user is entering the text, any suggestion about the second approach? I don't know where to start

Comment: You can add an onKeyUp watcher to each of the form text areas and fire the function onKeyUp against the value in the element.  I'll update the example above to reflect how that would work.